# simple asp.net password encoding authentication from a db tutorial

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I want to learn how to use authentication in your web appliction specially using some algorithm to encode your password so that it may be verified through a DB/file.

can someone share any project link???

Answer (score 0):

asp.net has a built-in membership infrastructure. It allows you to create users, roles, profiles and also save data to DB and use hashed passwords, so you don't need to handle all of that yourself.
Here is a reference to anything and everything you will ever want or need to know about asp.net membership:
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Comment: p.s. It also has built in controls for login, registration, password recovery, etc.